# How to fix Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1080, 428] error

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on Indian Spontaneous Expression dataset which has 428 images, each of shape `(1080, 1920, 3)`. Classification classes are 4 and its shape is `(428, 4)`. While splitting into training, validation and testing data using train_test_split:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

I am getting mentioned error.

I tried reshaping the data but anyhow I couldn't succeed.

```
import cv2 as cv
data=pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/ISED/details1.xlsx')
count=0
path = data['img_path']
for path in data['img_path']:
    count=count+1    
    temp1 = path.replace("'", "")
    imgpath = "/content/drive/My Drive/ISED/" + temp1
    imgFile = cv.imread(imgpath)
    X = np.asarray(imgFile)
print(X.shape)
print(count)
y = pd.get_dummies(data['emotion']).as_matrix()

# # #storing them using numpy
np.save('fdataXISED', X)
np.save('flabelsISED', y)
# #
print("Preprocessing Done")
print("Number of Features: "+str(len(X[0])))
print("Number of Labels: "+ str(len(y[0])))
print("Number of examples in dataset:"+str(len(X)))
print("X,y stored in fdataXISED.npy and flabelsISED.npy respectively")

num_features = 1920
num_labels = 4
batch_size = 64
epochs = 100
width, height = 1080, 1920

x = np.load('./fdataXISED.npy')
y = np.load('./flabelsISED.npy')
print(x.dtype)
x = x.astype(float)
x -= np.mean(x, axis=0)

x /= np.std(x, axis=0)
print(x.shape,"   ", y.shape)
#splitting into training, validation and testing data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, 
random_state=42)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, 
test_size=0.1, random_state=
```

I expect proper data split for training.

Comment: make sure that your `x` is in shape of  `(428,1080,1920,3)` and shape of `y` is `(428,4)`

Comment: Can you guide me expanding the dimension? The count variable I declared carries value 428.

Comment: What is the output of `print(x.shape,"   ", y.shape)`?

Comment: x: (1080, 1920, 3)     y:(428, 4)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here, `X = np.asarray(imgFile)` in `for path in data['img_path']:` So, `X` carries only last image. Please change like this,

```
X=[]
for path in data['img_path']:
    count=count+1    
    temp1 = path.replace("'", "")
    imgpath = "/content/drive/My Drive/ISED/" + temp1
    imgFile = cv.imread(imgpath)
    imgFile = np.asarray(imgFile)
    X.append(imgFile)
X = np.asarray(X)
print(X.shape)
print(count)
```

And at the end your `X` will be in shape of `(428,1080,1920,3)` and `y` must be in `(428,4)`

Error occurs because different number of samples in `X` and `y`.

Comment: X.append(imgFile) causes an error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Convert `imgFile ` to array first than try to append, have  a look at edited code.